# allure 2 cucumber JVM adapter and Cucumber 2 seem to be incompatible

Tags: maven, cucumber-jvm, allure

I'm trying to use Cucumber JVM 2 in conjunction with Allure 2 and I'm facing a trouble. When I try to run my Maven project - below error shows up:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: 
io.qameta.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureCucumberJvm. It does not implement 
cucumber.api.Plugin
```

I'm trying to specify Allure plugin using CucumberOptions like so:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions
(                 
  features="src/test/resources/com/ss/cuketest/features/SomeFeature.feature"
        ,   glue="com/ss/cuketest/steps"
        ,   plugin= {"io.qameta.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureCucumberJvm"}
)
public class SomeRunner {

}
```

AllureCucumberJvm declaration looks like below:

```
public class AllureCucumberJvm implements Reporter, Formatter
```

So the question is if the Allure's 2 Cucumber JVM adapter is compatible with Cucumber JVM 2? Or may be I should use something else?

PS: in my pom I use below dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-BETA21</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/tree/master/allure-cucumber2-jvm ?
This is adaptive for cucumber-jvm2

Comment: Thank you Viktor, I can't believe I was unable to find it on Google.

Answer (score 3):

According to Cucumber source file [cucumber.api.Plugin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/Plugin.java) it's now required that any plugin to implement one of below interfaces:

```
* <li>{@link cucumber.api.StepDefinitionReporter}</li>
 * <li>{@link cucumber.api.SummaryPrinter}</li>
 * <li>{@link cucumber.api.formatter.Formatter}</li>
```

However [AllureCucumberJvm](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/blob/master/allure-cucumber-jvm/src/main/java/io/qameta/allure/cucumberjvm/AllureCucumberJvm.java) implements

```
gherkin.formatter.Formatter
```

instead. So writing a simple extension to AllureCucumberJvm which implements Plugin interface unsurprisingly didn't help (my tests run fine though).

I believe this should be addressed by Allure team.

Comment: Keep in mind that source code linked is for cucumber v4.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on [Viktor Sidochenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48605197/1644036), here're the required lines in the POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-cucumber2-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>
                -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber2jvm.AllureCucumber2Jvm"
            </argLine>
```